# Version number comparison in Python

Tags: python, string-comparison

I want to write a `cmp`-like function that compares two version numbers and returns `-1`, `0`, or `1` based on their compared values.

- Return `-1` if version A is older than version B
- Return `0` if versions A and B are equivalent
- Return `1` if version A is newer than version B

Each subsection is supposed to be interpreted as a number, therefore 1.10 > 1.1.

Desired function outputs are

```
mycmp('1.0', '1') == 0
mycmp('1.0.0', '1') == 0
mycmp('1', '1.0.0.1') == -1
mycmp('12.10', '11.0.0.0.0') == 1
...
```

And here is my implementation, open for improvement:

```
def mycmp(version1, version2):
    parts1 = [int(x) for x in version1.split('.')]
    parts2 = [int(x) for x in version2.split('.')]

    # fill up the shorter version with zeros ...
    lendiff = len(parts1) - len(parts2)
    if lendiff > 0:
        parts2.extend([0] * lendiff)
    elif lendiff < 0:
        parts1.extend([0] * (-lendiff))

    for i, p in enumerate(parts1):
        ret = cmp(p, parts2[i])
        if ret: return ret
    return 0
```

I'm using Python 2.4.5 btw. (installed at my working place ...).

Here's a small 'test suite' you can use

```
assert mycmp('1', '2') == -1
assert mycmp('2', '1') == 1
assert mycmp('1', '1') == 0
assert mycmp('1.0', '1') == 0
assert mycmp('1', '1.000') == 0
assert mycmp('12.01', '12.1') == 0
assert mycmp('13.0.1', '13.00.02') == -1
assert mycmp('1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1') == 0
assert mycmp('1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.1') == 1
assert mycmp('1.1.3', '1.1.3.000') == 0
assert mycmp('3.1.1.0', '3.1.2.10') == -1
assert mycmp('1.1', '1.10') == -1
```

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion -- it might be worth implementing Debian's algorithm for version number comparison (basically, alternating sorting of non-numeric and numeric parts). The algorithm is described [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html) (beginning at "The strings are compared from left to right").

Comment: Blargh. The subset of markdown supported in comments never fails to confuse me. The link works anyway, even if it looks stupid.

Comment: In case future readers need this for user-agent version parsing, I recommend a [dedicated library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927552/parsing-http-user-agent-string/10109978#10109978) as the historical variation it too wide.

Comment: @hobbs. That is basically what [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare version strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/compare-version-strings-in-python)

Comment: Even though the question here is older, it appears [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/compare-version-strings-in-python) has been anointed as the canonical one, as many, many questions are closed as duplicates of that one.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Remove the uninteresting part of the string (trailing zeroes and dots), and then compare the lists of numbers.

```
import re

def mycmp(version1, version2):
    def normalize(v):
        return [int(x) for x in re.sub(r'(\.0+)*$','', v).split(".")]
    return cmp(normalize(version1), normalize(version2))
```

This is the same approach as Pär Wieslander, but a bit more compact:

Here are some tests, thanks to "[How to compare two strings in dot separated version format in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/how-to-compare-two-strings-in-dot-separated-version-format-in-bash/4025065#4025065)":

```
assert mycmp("1", "1") == 0
assert mycmp("2.1", "2.2") < 0
assert mycmp("3.0.4.10", "3.0.4.2") > 0
assert mycmp("4.08", "4.08.01") < 0
assert mycmp("3.2.1.9.8144", "3.2") > 0
assert mycmp("3.2", "3.2.1.9.8144") < 0
assert mycmp("1.2", "2.1") < 0
assert mycmp("2.1", "1.2") > 0
assert mycmp("5.6.7", "5.6.7") == 0
assert mycmp("1.01.1", "1.1.1") == 0
assert mycmp("1.1.1", "1.01.1") == 0
assert mycmp("1", "1.0") == 0
assert mycmp("1.0", "1") == 0
assert mycmp("1.0", "1.0.1") < 0
assert mycmp("1.0.1", "1.0") > 0
assert mycmp("1.0.2.0", "1.0.2") == 0
```

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work, the `rstrip(".0")` will change ".10" to ".1" in "1.0.10".

Comment: Sorry, but with your function:
mycmp('1.1', '1.10') == 0

Comment: With the regex use, the problem  mentioned above is fixed.

Comment: Now you've merged all the good ideas from the others into your solution ... :-P still, this is pretty much what I'd do after all. I'll accept this answer. Thanks, everyone

Comment: Heh. First, Pär answered while I was testing my solution - and when I switched to regexes, I didn't read the new answers - I'll go upvote the ones I "copied" now :)

Comment: Fails for some firefox versions, [available here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/). eg. 3.0a2

Comment: Yes, the question doesn't involve version numbers with letters in them.

Comment: Note cmp() has been removed in Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Answer (score 293):

How about using Python's `distutils.version.StrictVersion`?

```
>>> from distutils.version import StrictVersion
>>> StrictVersion('10.4.10') > StrictVersion('10.4.9')
True
```

So for your `cmp` function:

```
>>> cmp = lambda x, y: StrictVersion(x).__cmp__(y)
>>> cmp("10.4.10", "10.4.11")
-1
```

If you want to compare version numbers that are more complex `distutils.version.LooseVersion` will be more useful, however be sure to only compare the same types.

```
>>> from distutils.version import LooseVersion, StrictVersion
>>> LooseVersion('1.4c3') > LooseVersion('1.3')
True
>>> LooseVersion('1.4c3') > StrictVersion('1.3')  # different types
False
```

`LooseVersion` isn't the most intelligent tool, and can easily be tricked:

```
>>> LooseVersion('1.4') > LooseVersion('1.4-rc1')
False
```

To have success with this breed, you'll need to step outside the standard library and use [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s parsing utility [`parse_version`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#parsing-utilities).

```
>>> from pkg_resources import parse_version
>>> parse_version('1.4') > parse_version('1.4-rc2')
True
```

So depending on your specific use-case, you'll need to decide whether the builtin `distutils` tools are enough, or if it's warranted to add as a dependency `setuptools`.

Comment: seems to make the most sense to just use what is already there :)

Comment: Nice! Did you figure this out by reading the source? I can't find docs for distutils.version anywhere :-/

Comment: I don't think there are any docs. Yes I was reading through the source a while back when I was considering writing my own packaging solution, but then I found distutils2.

Comment: Any time you can't find documentation, try importing the package and use help().

Comment: Be aware though, that `StrictVersion` **ONLY** works with up to a three number version. It fails for things like `0.4.3.6`!

Comment: @bradley.ayers Thus I would recommend `parse_version`.

Comment: Distribute appears to be a deprecated fork of Setuptools (according to https://pythonhosted.org/distribute/). The documentation link to `parse_version` is also broken.

Comment: Every instance of `distribute` in this answer should be replaced by `setuptools`, which comes bundled with the `pkg_resources` package and has since... like, _ever_. Likewise, this is the [official documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#id33) for the `pkg_resources.parse_version()` function bundled with `setuptools`.

Comment: All variants fail with the xorg-server versioning: `1.19.6+13+gd0d1a694f-1 < 1.19.6-2`

Comment: distutils has been removed from python3.12. What's the best alternative?

Answer (score 31):

Is *reuse* considered elegance in this instance? :)

```
# pkg_resources is in setuptools
# See http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#parsing-utilities
def mycmp(a, b):
    from pkg_resources import parse_version as V
    return cmp(V(a),V(b))
```

Comment: Hmm, it's not so elegant when you refer to something [outside the standard library](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0365/) without explaining where to get it. I submitted an edit to include the URL.  Personally I prefer to use distutils - it doesn't seem worth the effort to pull in 3rd party software for so simple a task.

Comment: @adam-spiers _wut?_ Did you even read the commentary? `pkg_resources` is a `setuptools`-bundled package. Since `setuptools` is effectively mandatory on all Python installations, `pkg_resources` is effectively available everywhere. That said, the `distutils.version` subpackage is also useful – though considerably less intelligent than the higher-level `pkg_resources.parse_version()` function. Which you should leverage depends on what degree of insanity you expect in version strings.

Comment: @CecilCurry Yes of course I read the comment(ary), which is why I edited it to make it better, and then stated that I had. Presumably you're not disagreeing with my statement that `setuptools` is outside the standard library, and instead with my stated preference for `distutils` *in this case*. So what exactly do you mean by "effectively mandatory", and please can you provide evidence that it was "effectively mandatory" 4.5 years ago when I wrote this comment?

Answer (score 12):

No need to iterate over the version tuples. The built in comparison operator on lists and tuples already works exactly like you want it. You'll just need to zero extend the version lists to the corresponding length. With python 2.6 you can use izip_longest to pad the sequences.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def version_cmp(v1, v2):
    parts1, parts2 = [map(int, v.split('.')) for v in [v1, v2]]
    parts1, parts2 = zip(*izip_longest(parts1, parts2, fillvalue=0))
    return cmp(parts1, parts2)
```

With lower versions, some map hackery is required.

```
def version_cmp(v1, v2):
    parts1, parts2 = [map(int, v.split('.')) for v in [v1, v2]]
    parts1, parts2 = zip(*map(lambda p1,p2: (p1 or 0, p2 or 0), parts1, parts2))
    return cmp(parts1, parts2)
```

Comment: Cool, but hard to understand for someone who can't read code like prose. :) Well, I assume you can only shorten the solution at the cost of readability ...

Answer (score 10):

This is a little more compact than your suggestion.  Rather than filling the shorter version with zeros, I'm removing trailing zeros from the version lists after splitting.

```
def normalize_version(v):
    parts = [int(x) for x in v.split(".")]
    while parts[-1] == 0:
        parts.pop()
    return parts

def mycmp(v1, v2):
    return cmp(normalize_version(v1), normalize_version(v2))
```

Answer (score 7):

Remove trailing `.0` and `.00` with regex, `split` and use `cmp` function which compares arrays correctly:

```
def mycmp(v1,v2):
 c1=map(int,re.sub('(\.0+)+\Z','',v1).split('.'))
 c2=map(int,re.sub('(\.0+)+\Z','',v2).split('.'))
 return cmp(c1,c2)
```

And, of course, you can convert it to a one-liner if you don't mind the long lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
def compare_version(v1, v2):
    return cmp(*tuple(zip(*map(lambda x, y: (x or 0, y or 0), 
           [int(x) for x in v1.split('.')], [int(y) for y in v2.split('.')]))))
```

It's a one liner (split for legability). Not sure about readable...

Comment: Yes! And shrunk even further (`tuple` is not needed btw):
`cmp(*zip(*map(lambda x,y:(x or 0,y or 0), map(int,v1.split('.')), map(int,v2.split('.')) )))`

Answer (score 2):

Lists are comparable in Python, so if someone converts the strings representing the numbers into integers, the basic Python comparison can be used with success.

I needed to extend this approach a bit because I use Python3x where the `cmp` function does not exist any more. I had to emulate `cmp(a,b)` with `(a > b) - (a < b)`. And, version numbers are not that clean at all, and can contain all kind of other alphanumeric characters. There are cases when the function can't tell the order so it returns `False` (see the first example).

So I'm posting this even if the question is old and answered already, because it may save a few minutes in someone's life.

```
import re

def _preprocess(v, separator, ignorecase):
    if ignorecase: v = v.lower()
    return [int(x) if x.isdigit() else [int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for y in re.findall("\d+|[a-zA-Z]+", x)] for x in v.split(separator)]

def compare(a, b, separator = '.', ignorecase = True):
    a = _preprocess(a, separator, ignorecase)
    b = _preprocess(b, separator, ignorecase)
    try:
        return (a > b) - (a < b)
    except:
        return False

print(compare('1.0', 'beta13'))    
print(compare('1.1.2', '1.1.2'))
print(compare('1.2.2', '1.1.2'))
print(compare('1.1.beta1', '1.1.beta2'))
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to pull in an external dependency here is my attempt written for Python 3.x.

`rc`, `rel` (and possibly one could add `c`) are regarded as "release candidate" and divide the version number into two parts and if missing the value of the second part is high (999). Else letters produce a split and are dealt as sub-numbers via base-36 code.

```
import re
from itertools import chain
def compare_version(version1,version2):
    '''compares two version numbers
    >>> compare_version('1', '2') < 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('2', '1') > 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1', '1') == 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.0', '1') == 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1', '1.000') == 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('12.01', '12.1') == 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('13.0.1', '13.00.02') <0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1') == 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.1') >0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.1.3', '1.1.3.000') == 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('3.1.1.0', '3.1.2.10') <0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.1', '1.10') <0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.1.2','1.1.2') == 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.1.2','1.1.1') > 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.2','1.1.1') > 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.1.1-rc2','1.1.1-rc1') > 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.1.1a-rc2','1.1.1a-rc1') > 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.1.10-rc1','1.1.1a-rc2') > 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.1.1a-rc2','1.1.2-rc1') < 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.11','1.10.9') > 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.4','1.4-rc1') > 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('1.4c3','1.3') > 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('2.8.7rel.2','2.8.7rel.1') > 0
    True
    >>> compare_version('2.8.7.1rel.2','2.8.7rel.1') > 0
    True

    '''
    chn = lambda x:chain.from_iterable(x)
    def split_chrs(strings,chars):
        for ch in chars:
            strings = chn( [e.split(ch) for e in strings] )
        return strings
    split_digit_char=lambda x:[s for s in re.split(r'([a-zA-Z]+)',x) if len(s)>0]
    splt = lambda x:[split_digit_char(y) for y in split_chrs([x],'.-_')]
    def pad(c1,c2,f='0'):
        while len(c1) > len(c2): c2+=[f]
        while len(c2) > len(c1): c1+=[f]
    def base_code(ints,base):
        res=0
        for i in ints:
            res=base*res+i
        return res
    ABS = lambda lst: [abs(x) for x in lst]
    def cmp(v1,v2):
        c1 = splt(v1)
        c2 = splt(v2)
        pad(c1,c2,['0'])
        for i in range(len(c1)): pad(c1[i],c2[i])
        cc1 = [int(c,36) for c in chn(c1)]
        cc2 = [int(c,36) for c in chn(c2)]
        maxint = max(ABS(cc1+cc2))+1
        return base_code(cc1,maxint) - base_code(cc2,maxint)
    v_main_1, v_sub_1 = version1,'999'
    v_main_2, v_sub_2 = version2,'999'
    try:
        v_main_1, v_sub_1 = tuple(re.split('rel|rc',version1))
    except:
        pass
    try:
        v_main_2, v_sub_2 = tuple(re.split('rel|rc',version2))
    except:
        pass
    cmp_res=[cmp(v_main_1,v_main_2),cmp(v_sub_1,v_sub_2)]
    res = base_code(cmp_res,max(ABS(cmp_res))+1)
    return res


import random
from functools import cmp_to_key
random.shuffle(versions)
versions.sort(key=cmp_to_key(compare_version))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
def version_compare(v1, v2, op=None):
    _map = {
        '<': [-1],
        'lt': [-1],
        '<=': [-1, 0],
        'le': [-1, 0],
        '>': [1],
        'gt': [1],
        '>=': [1, 0],
        'ge': [1, 0],
        '==': [0],
        'eq': [0],
        '!=': [-1, 1],
        'ne': [-1, 1],
        '<>': [-1, 1]
    }
    v1 = StrictVersion(v1)
    v2 = StrictVersion(v2)
    result = cmp(v1, v2)
    if op:
        assert op in _map.keys()
        return result in _map[op]
    return result
```

Implement for php `version_compare`, except "=". Because it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The most difficult to read solution, but a one-liner nevertheless! and using iterators to be fast.

```
next((c for c in imap(lambda x,y:cmp(int(x or 0),int(y or 0)),
            v1.split('.'),v2.split('.')) if c), 0)
```

that is for Python2.6 and 3.+ btw, Python 2.5 and older need to catch the StopIteration.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in order to be able to parse and compare the Debian package version string. Please notice that it is not strict with the character validation.

This might be helpful as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Read <https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version> for further informations.

class CommonVersion(object):
    def __init__(self, version_string):
        self.version_string = version_string
        self.tags = []
        self.parse()

    def parse(self):
        parts = self.version_string.split('~')
        self.version_string = parts[0]
        if len(parts) > 1:
            self.tags = parts[1:]


    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.version_string < other.version_string:
            return True
        for index, tag in enumerate(self.tags):
            if index not in other.tags:
                return True
            if self.tags[index] < other.tags[index]:
                return True

    @staticmethod
    def create(version_string):
        return UpstreamVersion(version_string)

class UpstreamVersion(CommonVersion):
    pass

class DebianMaintainerVersion(CommonVersion):
    pass

class CompoundDebianVersion(object):
    def __init__(self, epoch, upstream_version, debian_version):
        self.epoch = epoch
        self.upstream_version = UpstreamVersion.create(upstream_version)
        self.debian_version = DebianMaintainerVersion.create(debian_version)

    @staticmethod
    def create(version_string):
        version_string = version_string.strip()
        epoch = 0
        upstream_version = None
        debian_version = '0'

        epoch_check = version_string.split(':')
        if epoch_check[0].isdigit():
            epoch = int(epoch_check[0])
            version_string = ':'.join(epoch_check[1:])
        debian_version_check = version_string.split('-')
        if len(debian_version_check) > 1:
            debian_version = debian_version_check[-1]
            version_string = '-'.join(debian_version_check[0:-1])

        upstream_version = version_string

        return CompoundDebianVersion(epoch, upstream_version, debian_version)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, vars(self))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.epoch < other.epoch:
            return True
        if self.upstream_version < other.upstream_version:
            return True
        if self.debian_version < other.debian_version:
            return True
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def lt(a, b):
        assert(CompoundDebianVersion.create(a) < CompoundDebianVersion.create(b))

    # test epoch
    lt('1:44.5.6', '2:44.5.6')
    lt('1:44.5.6', '1:44.5.7')
    lt('1:44.5.6', '1:44.5.7')
    lt('1:44.5.6', '2:44.5.6')
    lt('  44.5.6', '1:44.5.6')

    # test upstream version (plus tags)
    lt('1.2.3~rc7',          '1.2.3')
    lt('1.2.3~rc1',          '1.2.3~rc2')
    lt('1.2.3~rc1~nightly1', '1.2.3~rc1')
    lt('1.2.3~rc1~nightly2', '1.2.3~rc1')
    lt('1.2.3~rc1~nightly1', '1.2.3~rc1~nightly2')
    lt('1.2.3~rc1~nightly1', '1.2.3~rc2~nightly1')

    # test debian maintainer version
    lt('44.5.6-lts1', '44.5.6-lts12')
    lt('44.5.6-lts1', '44.5.7-lts1')
    lt('44.5.6-lts1', '44.5.7-lts2')
    lt('44.5.6-lts1', '44.5.6-lts2')
    lt('44.5.6-lts1', '44.5.6-lts2')
    lt('44.5.6',      '44.5.6-lts1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
def mycmp(v1, v2):
    import itertools as it
    f = lambda v: list(it.dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, map(int, v.split('.'))[::-1]))[::-1]
    return cmp(f(v1), f(v2))
```

One can use like this too:

```
import itertools as it
f = lambda v: list(it.dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, map(int, v.split('.'))[::-1]))[::-1]
f(v1) <  f(v2)
f(v1) == f(v2)
f(v1) >  f(v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this one on my project:

```
cmp(v1.split("."), v2.split(".")) >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Years later, but stil this question is on the top.

Here is my version sort function. It splits version into numbers and non-numbers sections. Numbers are compared as `int` rest as `str` (as parts of list items).

```py
def sort_version_2(data):
    def key(n):
        a = re.split(r'(\d+)', n)
        a[1::2] = map(int, a[1::2])
        return a
    return sorted(data, key=lambda n: key(n))
```

You can use function `key` as kind of custom `Version` type with compare operators. If out really want to use `cmp` you can do it like in this example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490617/9935708

```
def Version(s):
    s = re.sub(r'(\.0*)*$', '', s)  # to avoid ".0" at end
    a = re.split(r'(\d+)', s)
    a[1::2] = map(int, a[1::2])
    return a

def mycmp(a, b):
    a, b = Version(a), Version(b)
    return (a > b) - (a < b)  # DSM's answer
```

Test suite passes.

Answer (score -1):

My preferred solution:

Padding the string with extra zeroes and just using the four first is easy to understand,
doesn't require any regex and the lambda is more or less readable. I use two lines for readability, for me elegance is short and simple.

```
def mycmp(version1,version2):
  tup = lambda x: [int(y) for y in (x+'.0.0.0.0').split('.')][:4]
  return cmp(tup(version1),tup(version2))
```

Answer (score -2):

This is my solution (written in C, sorry). I hope you'll find it useful

```
int compare_versions(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    while(*s1 && *s2) {
        if(isdigit(*s1) && isdigit(*s2)) {
            /* compare as two decimal integers */
            int s1_i = strtol(s1, &s1, 10);
            int s2_i = strtol(s2, &s2, 10);

            if(s1_i != s2_i) return s1_i - s2_i;
        } else {
            /* compare as two strings */
            while(*s1 && !isdigit(*s1) && *s2 == *s1) {
                s1++;
                s2++;
            }

            int s1_i = isdigit(*s1) ? 0 : *s1;
            int s2_i = isdigit(*s2) ? 0 : *s2;

            if(s1_i != s2_i) return s1_i - s2_i;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```