# How to use cmp() in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison-operators

I cannot get the command `cmp()` to work in Python 3.

Here is the code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
c = cmp(a,b)
print (c)
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Dropbox\Code\a = [1,2,3]", line 3, in <module>
    c = cmp(a,b)
 NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?  2.x has `cmp()`, but 3.x does not.  I suspect 3.x because of the parentheses after `print`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `cmp` doesn't exist in Python 3.  If you really want it, you could define it yourself:

```
def cmp(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)
```

which is taken from the original [What's New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons).  It's pretty rare -- though not unheard of -- that it's really needed, though, so you might want to think about whether it's actually the best way to do whatever it is you're up to.

Comment: maybe need to cast the booleans like: def cmp(a, b):
    return int(a > b) - int(a < b)

Comment: Following @Oren's comment, if a and b are numpy variables, the `(a > b)` and `(a <b)` variables may be of type numpy.bool_. 
The numpy.bool_ type doesn't support subtraction.
Using `bool(a > b) - bool(a < b)` solves this.

Answer (score 14):

In Python 3.x you can `import operator` and use operator module's `eq()`, `lt()`, etc... instead of `cmp()`

Answer (score 1):

When the sign is needed, probably safest alternative is using math.copysign:

```
import math
ang = -2
# alternative for cmp(ang, 0):
math.copysign(1, ang)

# Result: -1
```

In particular if ang is of np.float64 type because of depreciation of the '-' operator.
Example:

```
import numpy as np

def cmp_0(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)

ang = np.float64(-2)
cmp_0(ang, 0)

# Result:
# DeprecationWarning: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is deprecated, 
# use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.
```

instead one could use:

```
def cmp_0(a, b):
    return bool(a > b) - bool(a < b)

ang = np.float64(-2)
cmp(ang, 0)
# Result: -1
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for `0`

Answer (score 0):

adding to @maxin's answer, in `python 3.x`, if you want to compare two lists of tuples
`a` and `b`

```
import operator

a = [(1,2),(3,4)]
b = [(3,4),(1,2)]
# convert both lists to sets before calling the eq function
print(operator.eq(set(a),set(b))) #True
```

Answer (score 0):

While in the general case, these are all good replacements for `cmp()`, for the actual use case given by the original poster, surely

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
c = a != b
print(c)
```

or just

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
print(a != b)
```

would work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this easier way

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]
c=not(a!=b)
c
True
```

Answer (score -1):

If a or b is a class object,
then the above answers will have the compilation error as below:
For example: a is Class Clock:

```
  File "01_ClockClass_lab16.py", line 14, in cmp
    return (a > b) - (a < b)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Clock' and 'Clock'
```

Change the type with int() to remove the error:

```
def cmp(a, b):
    return (int(a) > int(b)) - (int(a) < int(b))
```

Comment: Surely you should define comparison operators in your custom class, rather than casting everything to int?

Answer (score -4):

This `cmp()` function works only on Python version 2.x, if you try to use it in version 3.x it will give an error:

```
NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

See the code below:

```
a=60
b=90
print(cmp(a,b))
```

output:

```
-1
```

While comparing integers cmp() just performs subtraction of its argument i.e in this case a-b, if subtraction is -ve it returns -1 i.e a<b
if subtraction is +ve it returns 1 i.e a>b

```
a=90
b=60
print(cmp(a,b))
```

output:

```
1
```

Again:

```
a="abc"
b="abc"
print(cmp(a,b))
```

output:

```
0
```

when both the arguments are equal i.e a=b, it returns 0 as output. Here, we have passed two string type of values. Here, cmp() compares both the strings character by character and if found same then returns 0.

Answer (score -4):

One simple way is to use `a - b` and check the sign.

```py
def cmp(a, b):
    return a - b
```

```bash
if a < b, negative

if a = b, zero

if a > b, positive
```

Comment: `cmp` should also work on non numeric types. `str` for example. It's important that the function really only returns -1, 0, or 1 for proper interop with legacy code.