# Sort a dictionary by values in ascending order and by keys in descending order

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I am trying to sort a dictionary, the order which I want to follow is that first, the dictionary should be sorted in increasing order by values and if the values for two or more keys are equal then I want to sort the dictionary by the keys in descending order.

Here is the code:

```
dictionary = {0: 150, 1: 151, 2: 150, 3: 101, 4: 107}
print(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])))
```

I want the output to be the following:
`[(3, 101), (4, 107), (2, 150), (0, 150), (1, 151)]`

But the output is:
`[(3, 101), (4, 107), (0, 150), (2, 150), (1, 151)]`

Comment: Given that the values are numeric, you can use `sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))`

Comment: If you want the two values to simultaneously be sorted in opposite directions, you'll have to make one of them *negative*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Any generic suggestions for how if neither are numeric? (All I could think of previously was writing a combined `cmp` function along the lines of `cmp1 or cmp2` and using `cmp_to_key`.)

Comment: What I wrote above is the opposite of what was asked for (although the general principle holds) - corrected in my answer below.

Comment: Here, you're using sorted() which takes ascending order as default value

Comment: Isn't the question worth upvoting?

Comment: @Sherlock It is a reasonable question, and on this occasion okay yes I will upvote it. *However*, soliciting votes is not really a good habit. Fundamentally, you ask a question because you would like to have it answered, rather than to earn points from it.

Comment: It's not at all about points, It's about that genuine questions deserve appreciation/criticism which is kind of feedback for the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the values are numeric here, you can use negation as having the same effect as reversing the sort order:

```
sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[0]))
```

For the more generic case where you can't rely on the values being numeric, here is a possible approach, although there may be a better way.

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def cmp(a, b):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490617/13596037
    return (a > b) - (a < b)

def cmp_items(a, b):
    """
    compare by second item forward, or if they are the same then use first item
    in reverse direction (returns -1/0/1)
    """
    return cmp(a[1], b[1]) or cmp(b[0], a[0])

dictionary = {0: 150, 1: 151, 2: 150, 3: 101, 4: 107}

print(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=cmp_to_key(cmp_items)))
```

Comment: If anyone has a better way to do the generic case, please can you post an answer (and let me know).

Comment: Isn't the question worth upvoting?

Comment: (I have responded above.)