# Extract min value node

Tags: python, algorithm, nodes

I have the following class:

```
class Node:  
    def __init__(self, node, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.node = node    
        self.value = value  
        self.left = left    
        self.right = right  
        self.code = ''
```

I have a list of Node. The question is, how can I extract the node with the lowest `self.value` attribute?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer This appears to be a tree node, not a list

Comment: @Sergio Please show the code that includes the "list of node"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built-in `min` function with an anonymous function to access value parameter:

```
min(listNodes, key=lambda x: x.value)
```

Or you can define the rich comparison methods `__lt__` and `__eq__` in `Node` (you can define additional rich comparison methods, but these two are sufficient for ordering like `min`):

```
class Node:def __init__(self, node, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.node = node    
        self.value = value  
        self.left = left    
        self.right = right  
        self.code = '' 
 
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value
```

which will allow `min` to directly compare the nodes finding the minimum!

```
min(listNodes)
```

---

Before Python3, it was possible to use the now-deprecated `__cmp__` method to create all the rich comparison methods at once; see [Question About This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490366/how-to-use-cmp-in-python-3) and [Linked Official Notes](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons)

Comment: This assumes that `Node` is iterable...

Comment: @OneCricketeer I added the `__iter__` function to the class, but I'm not sure if it can work without it, as all the elements in the list are the same class type and lambda function is getting the value attribute

Comment: `return self` doesn't make sense for a `__iter__` definition. Assumably, OP wants `min([self.value, self.left.value, self.right.value])` (recursively)

Comment: note that `cmp` is gone in Python3, so (for this case) `__lt__` and `__eq__` should be defined instead (though practically the signature is the same) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490366/how-to-use-cmp-in-python-3