# `sorted(my_list, key = lambda x, y: ... )` possible?

Tags: python, string, sorting, lambda, key

If I want to sort a list of non-empty strings by this criteria -

`"x + y > y + x"` (for any `x = lst[i]`, `y = lst[j]` that `0 <= i < j < len(lst)`)

I know one way is to define a `my_key` class and put the logic in this class, then do `sorted(key=my_key)`. Another way is to use the `cmp_to_key` functool.

I wonder if it's also possible to use lambda expression instead here (without `cmp_to_key`)? Something like -

```
sorted(lst, key = lambda x, y: ((x+y > y+x) - (x+y < y+x))
```

(The above code doesn't work though because of missing positional argument.)

(Edit: The reason of not simply using `x > y` is for example `"21" > "2"` but `"21" + "2" < "2" + "21"`)

Comment: You'd need your `lambda` to return objects with an appropriate comparison method, and trying to stuff the class definition for that into a `lambda` is *way* too much of a mess to be worthwhile.

Comment: @user2357112 I see stuffing the class definition for that into a lambda is a mess. Is it still possible, or not possible at all?

Comment: @Egret: If you really want to write a giant `lambda x, *, _helper_type=type('HelperType', (), {'__init__': lambda self, elem: setattr(self, 'elem', elem), '__lt__': lambda self, other: ...` thing, you technically can, but it's not a good idea.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks. So the full code is `sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x, *, _helper_type=type('HelperType', (), {'__init__': lambda self, elem: setattr(self, 'elem', elem), '__lt__': lambda self, other: self.elem + other.elem < other.elem + self.elem}): _helper_type(x), reverse=True)`? This still helps me to learn the technicality though

Answer (score 1):

A comparison function should not return a Boolean value like your `lambda x, y: x+y > y+x` does, but instead a negative number if the first operand is considered less than the second, `0` if equal, or a positive number for greater-than, as documented in [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key).

You can follow the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490617/6890912) to create a comparison function that considers `x` less than `y` when `x + y` is greater than `y + x` and vice versa:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

lst = ['b', 'aa', 'bb', 'a']
print(sorted(lst,
    key=cmp_to_key(lambda x, y: ((a := x + y) < (b := y + x)) - (a > b))))
```

This outputs:

```
['b', 'bb', 'aa', 'a']
```

As noted in the comments, `'aa'` and `'a'` for example would be considered equal by your comparison function, in which case Python's sorting algorithm would retain their orignal order in the output.

Also as noted in the comments, your comparison function would not work for empty strings, since given `['a', '', '0']` for example, if the pairs of `'a', ''` and `'', '0'` are picked for comparison by the algorithm, `'a'` would be inferred as equal to `'0'`, but would be considered different if the pair of `'a', '0'` is picked instead, so you should make sure that your use case doesn't involve empty strings.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question. Is it possible to not use `cmp_to_key`?