# remove dict from list if one value is same and other value is lower

Tags: python

I have a list with dicts with version numbers

```py
my_list = [{'version': 'v1.2.3', 'major': '1.2'},
           {'version': 'v1.2.7', 'major': '1.2'},
           {'version': 'v1.3.7', 'major': '1.3'},
           {'version': 'v1.4.1a1', 'major': '1.4'},
           {'version': 'v1.3.8b1', 'major': '1.3'},
           {'version': 'v1.3.2', 'major': '1.3'}]
```

In the end I want this list only to have the latest version of each major version and have all alpha/beta versions removed.

```py
my_list = [{'version': 'v1.2.7', 'major': '1.2'},
           {'version': 'v1.3.7', 'major': '1.3'}]
```

My first thought was to make a new list and iterate through my list, if a major is not in the new list, it will be added, if it's in the new list, it will compare and replace. But I think there may be a more pythonic way to do so.

EDIT: there are also alpha and beta versions which I'd like to remove completely from the list.

Comment: I asked you a question. Can you answer it please? `Is order important for the output?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another case where `itertools.groupby` comes to the resque:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = [{'version': 'v1.2.3', 'major': '1.2'},
           {'version': 'v1.2.7', 'major': '1.2'},
           {'version': 'v1.3.7', 'major': '1.3'},
           {'version': 'v1.4.1a1', 'major': '1.4'},
           {'version': 'v1.3.8b1', 'major': '1.3'},
           {'version': 'v1.3.2', 'major': '1.3'}]

my_list_ = list(filter(lambda x: all(beta not in x['version'] for beta in ('a', 'b')), my_list))  # removing beta-versions

version_f = lambda y: [0 if any(beta in x for beta in ('a', 'b')) else int(x) for x in y['version'].replace('v', '').split('.')]
grouper = lambda x: x['major']

d = [max(k, key=version_f) for _, k in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=grouper), key=grouper)]
print(d)  # -> [{'version': 'v1.2.7', 'major': '1.2'}, {'version': 'v1.3.7', 'major': '1.3'}, {'version': 'v1.4.1a1', 'major': '1.4'}]
```

Notes:

- Do not use the name `list`. You are overwriting the Python built-in.
- If the `list-comprehension` is too big for your taste, break it down using *good-old* `for` loops. There is no crime in that.
- As @Coldspeed mentions, comparing versions is not so straightforward, so to showcase that, I took the liberty to modify your input a bit (added `{'version': 'v1.3.12', 'major': '1.3'}`) and made the `lambda` a bit more clever<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1.</sup>This works based on the Python built-in ordering scheme for `lists` of integers (`[1, 3, 10] > [1, 3, 7]` returns `True`).

Comment: Yes, this would be the most straightforward answer if ordering wasn't important with the output.

Comment: Keep in mind, however, that comparing versions isn't so straightforward. 10.0 is greater than 2.0 but your approach isn't going to pick up on that.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Is that better, or am I still missing something?

Comment: There's a question on SO that you might find useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714027/version-number-comparison

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Both examples you provided work. [Have a look](https://repl.it/repls/FloralwhitePaleFallowdeer). And the post you linked, utilizes the same principle

Comment: Okay, I'm satisfied. :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Then I am satisfied too. Let's see what OP thinks ;)

Comment: This is almost perfect! But I just saw, that I have also a1 and b2 versions which I like to completely ignore in that case. Your current solution throws an error because it's not an int.

Comment: @AndreasHubert Can you please edit your question then to include those *edge-cases* too?

Comment: No problem, I love nitpicking ;) BTW, no need to call `list()` inside `max`. Finally, a lambda is an anonymous function. If you name this anonymous function, you might as well use a function.

Comment: @AndreasHubert How about now?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis perfect! Thanks so much! Do you maybe know also good tutorials if it comes to such solutions? Because I never get this on my own with such things and always end up on StackOverflow :/

Comment: @AndreasHubert The difficult part you shown that you can do your self (the description of the algorithm in your question). Coding it, is not a big deal really; just break it down into small pieces and do one chunk at a time.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Expressing what I want is easy, but still I have problems to get my head around in python about sorting and grouping and filtering etc. And again I'm stuck right now ... will make a new question here :D

Answer (score 2):

## Your idea

Your idea is actually a good one. It is efficient and can be implemented in a relatively Pythonic way:

```
import re
releases = [{'version': 'v1.2.3', 'major': '1.2'},
            {'version': 'v1.2.7', 'major': '1.2'},
            {'version': 'v1.3.7', 'major': '1.3'},
            {'version': 'v1.4.1a1', 'major': '1.4'},
            {'version': 'v1.3.8b1', 'major': '1.3'},
            {'version': 'v1.3.2', 'major': '1.3'}]

stable_releases = [r for r in releases if 'a' not in r['version']
                                      and 'b' not in r['version']]

latest = {}

def major_minor_build(version):
    return [int(d) for d in re.findall('\d+', version)]

for release in stable_releases:
    version, major = release['version'], release['major']
    latest[major] = max([version, latest.get(major, '')],
                                  key=major_minor_build)

print(latest)
# {'1.2': 'v1.2.7', '1.3': 'v1.3.7'}
```

The output data is a dict of `(major, latest)` pairs, which probably is easier to work with than a list of dicts.

## SetuptoolsVersion

Versions can be tricky. Instead of reinventing the wheel, we could use [`pkg_resources.SetuptoolsVersion`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html). Comparisons are already implemented, so `max` and `sort` won't need any key. As a bonus, `is_prerelease` is True if the version is alpha or beta:

```
from pkg_resources import SetuptoolsVersion, parse_version
from itertools import groupby

def get_major(release):
    return release._version.release[:2]

mylist = [{'version': 'v1.2.3', 'major': '1.2'},
         {'version': 'v1.2.7', 'major': '1.2'},
         {'version': 'v1.3.7', 'major': '1.3'},
         {'version': 'v1.4.1a1', 'major': '1.4'},
         {'version': 'v1.3.8b1', 'major': '1.3'},
         {'version': 'v1.3.2', 'major': '1.3'}]

releases = [parse_version(r['version']) for r in mylist]
stable_releases = [r for r in releases if not r.is_prerelease]
stable_releases.sort()

print({major:max(group) for major, group in groupby(stable_releases, key=get_major)})
# {(1, 2): <Version('1.2.7')>, (1, 3): <Version('1.3.7')>}
```