# implement sorting for list of dictionary having versions as key in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm trying to use `StrictVersion` on the code below:

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
from operator import itemgetter

v = [{'ver': '1.1.12'},{'ver': '1.0.0'},{'ver': '1.3.3'},{'ver': '1.0.12'},{'ver': '1.0.2'}]
v.sort(key=itemgetter("ver"),reverse=True)
```

This is sorting based on version with below code but it's not sorting properly in above code.

```
versions = ["1.1.2", "1.0.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2"]
versions.sort(key=StrictVersion,reverse=True)
```

How to use `key=StrictVersion` on above with key? Or is there an alternative?.

Comment: Do you want `v.sort(key=lambda x: StrictVersion(x['ver']),reverse=True)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972866/532312 ?

Comment: I don't think you need `StrictVersion` strictly for this sorting. `sorted(v, key = lambda x: x['ver'], reverse = True)`.

Comment: `v.sort(key = lambda x:StrictVersion( x['ver']),reverse=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v.sort(key = lambda x:StrictVersion( x['ver']),reverse=True)
[{'ver': '1.3.3'},
 {'ver': '1.1.12'},
 {'ver': '1.0.12'},
 {'ver': '1.0.2'},
 {'ver': '1.0.0'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

all the keys are the same, how do you intend on sorting the keys when they all are the same?

for the version part you can sort using:

```
list_to_sort = ['1.1.4', '1.6.9', '1.1.2']
sorted(list_to_sort, key=lambda version: int(''.join(["%02X" % int(i) for i in version.split('.')]), 16))
```

Comment: its not only list, its list of dictionary with key,value pair. this will not work for me.