# Extract bot name from user-agent string-Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to extract the botname with its version from user-agent strings. I tried using split function. But since the way of displaying user-agent string is different from one crawler to the other what is the best way to get my expected out put?(Please consider that i need a general solution)

Input(user-agent strings)

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/4.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)
msnbot/2.0b (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)
```

Expected output

```
Googlebot/2.1
AhrefsBot/4.0
msnbot/2.0b
```

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927552/parsing-http-user-agent-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

```
import re

lines = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/4.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)',
    'msnbot/2.0b (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)'
]

botname = re.compile('\w+bot/[.\w]+', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
for line in lines:
    matched = botname.search(line)
    if matched:
        print(matched.group())
```

prints

```
Googlebot/2.1
AhrefsBot/4.0
msnbot/2.0b
```

assumed that bot agent names contain `bot/`.

Comment: Thanks falsetru!...:)This is what I expected!